# black screen on android 12 devices after launching for builds with api 31 and above

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

i have a serious problem witch is having a black screen on android 12 devices after splash screen for builds with api 31, and api 30 and below devices it works. and i have tested it on unity 2018 and 2017 and i get the same results, and for more details please see the logs :

```js
2022-08-13 16:59:16.558 5610-5610/? E/USNET: USNET: appName: com.minions.text
2022-08-13 16:59:22.029 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: [EGL] Attaching window :0xe57d1528
2022-08-13 16:59:22.029 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: Initialize engine version: 2017.4.40f1 (6e14067f8a9a)
2022-08-13 16:59:22.047 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: AudioManager: Selecting OpenSL output...
2022-08-13 16:59:22.051 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/om.minions.tex: PlayerBase::PlayerBase()
2022-08-13 16:59:22.051 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/om.minions.tex: TrackPlayerBase::TrackPlayerBase()
2022-08-13 16:59:22.051 5610-5644/com.minions.text I/libOpenSLES: Emulating old channel mask behavior (ignoring positional mask 0x3, using default mask 0x3 based on channel count of 2)
2022-08-13 16:59:22.051 5610-5644/com.minions.text W/AudioTrack: set(): notificationFrames=-10 clamped to the range -1 to -8
2022-08-13 16:59:22.064 5610-5644/com.minions.text I/AudioTrack: createTrack_l(0): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST successful; frameCount 0 -> 1536
2022-08-13 16:59:22.074 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
2022-08-13 16:59:22.296 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: - Completed reload, in  0.222 seconds
2022-08-13 16:59:22.388 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: WARNING: Shader 
2022-08-13 16:59:22.389 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
2022-08-13 16:59:22.389 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: WARNING: Shader 
2022-08-13 16:59:22.389 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Setting to default shader.
2022-08-13 16:59:22.389 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: WARNING: Shader 
2022-08-13 16:59:22.389 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
2022-08-13 16:59:22.389 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: WARNING: Shader 
2022-08-13 16:59:22.389 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Setting to default shader.
2022-08-13 16:59:22.390 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: PlayerInitEngineGraphics OK
2022-08-13 16:59:22.397 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: Found 51 native sensors
2022-08-13 16:59:22.399 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.002393 / 0.00s ; LSM6DSO Accelerometer / STMicro 
2022-08-13 16:59:22.400 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.002393 / 0.00s ; LSM6DSO Accelerometer / STMicro 
2022-08-13 16:59:22.409 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: SetWindow 0 0xe57d1528
2022-08-13 16:59:22.410 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: [EGL] Attaching window :0xe57d1528
2022-08-13 16:59:22.423 5610-5644/com.minions.text V/MediaRouter: Selecting route: RouteInfo{ name=Phone, description=null, status=null, category=RouteCategory{ name=System types=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO  groupable=false }, supportedTypes=ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_AUDIO ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO , presentationDisplay=null }
2022-08-13 16:59:22.424 5610-5644/com.minions.text I/MediaRouter: Skip setBluetoothA2dpOn(): types=8388615, isPlaybackActive()=true, BT route=null
2022-08-13 16:59:22.560 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: UnloadTime: 3.755000 ms
2022-08-13 16:59:22.570 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: UUID: 4b6c7e5e6757e9e2 => deb7e6fc9f3fdd5c2051e2c6a4534307
2022-08-13 16:59:22.678 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/DecorView: notifyKeepScreenOnChanged: keepScreenOn=false
2022-08-13 16:59:22.691 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.002393 / 0.00s ; LSM6DSO Accelerometer / STMicro 
2022-08-13 16:59:22.695 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,142,1440,3040) new=(0,142,1440,3040) req=(1440,2898)0 dur=12 res=0x1 s={true 3850173424} ch=false fn=5
2022-08-13 16:59:22.695 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: updateBoundsLayer: t = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@ebfee10 sc = Surface(name=Bounds for - com.minions.text/com.minions.text.UnityPlayerActivity@0)/@0x2a16d09 frame = 5
2022-08-13 16:59:22.696 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: mWNT: t = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@ebfee10 fN = 5 android.view.ViewRootImpl.prepareSurfaces:2752 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:3998 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2893 
2022-08-13 16:59:22.696 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: mWNT: merge t to BBQ
2022-08-13 16:59:22.696 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147600208; UID 12468; state: ENABLED
2022-08-13 16:59:22.702 5610-5644/com.minions.text D/Unity: Choreographer available: Enabling VSYNC timing
2022-08-13 16:59:37.734 5610-5610/com.minions.text D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2022-08-13 16:59:37.734 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2022-08-13 16:59:38.094 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/Unity: onPause
2022-08-13 16:59:40.824 5610-5694/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: Resizing android.view.ViewRootImpl@9f2fb40: frame=[0,142][1440,3040] reportDraw=true forceLayout=false backDropFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2898)
2022-08-13 16:59:42.095 5610-5610/com.minions.text W/Unity: Timeout while trying to pause the Unity Engine.
2022-08-13 16:59:42.113 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: handleAppVisibility mAppVisible=true visible=false
2022-08-13 16:59:42.117 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: stopped(true) old=false
2022-08-13 16:59:42.117 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: windowStopped(true) false android.view.SurfaceView{cf770a VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-1440,2898 aid=1073741824} of ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]
2022-08-13 16:59:42.118 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: pST: sr = Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2898) sw = 1440 sh = 2898
2022-08-13 16:59:42.119 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: onSSPAndSRT: pl = 0 pt = 0 sx = 1.0 sy = 1.0
2022-08-13 16:59:42.119 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: pST: mTmpTransaction.apply, mTmpTransaction = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@bef161
2022-08-13 16:59:42.120 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: surfaceDestroyed callback.size 1 #1 android.view.SurfaceView{cf770a VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-1440,2898 aid=1073741824}
2022-08-13 16:59:46.121 5610-5610/com.minions.text W/Unity: Timeout while trying detaching primary window.
2022-08-13 16:59:46.121 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: updateSurface: mVisible = false mSurface.isValid() = true
2022-08-13 16:59:46.122 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: remove() android.view.SurfaceView{cf770a VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-1440,2898 aid=1073741824} Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.minions.text/com.minions.text.UnityPlayerActivity@cf770a@0)/@0x882aa79
2022-08-13 16:59:46.148 5610-5610/com.minions.text D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2022-08-13 16:59:46.148 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2022-08-13 16:59:46.160 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: handleAppVisibility mAppVisible=false visible=true
2022-08-13 16:59:46.160 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: stopped(false) old=true
2022-08-13 16:59:46.162 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: stopped(false) old=false
2022-08-13 16:59:46.162 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/Unity: onResume
2022-08-13 16:59:46.163 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/DecorView: notifyKeepScreenOnChanged: keepScreenOn=false
2022-08-13 16:59:46.165 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: handleResized, msg = 5 frames=ClientWindowFrames{frame=[0,142][1440,3040] display=[0,142][1440,3040] backdrop=[0,0][1440,2898]} forceNextWindowRelayout=false displayId=0 frameChanged=false backdropFrameChanged=false configChanged=false displayChanged=false mNextDrawUseBlastSync=false mergedConfiguration={mGlobalConfig={1.1 604mcc1mnc [en_US] ldltr sw411dp w411dp h812dp 560dpi nrml long hdr widecg port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 3040) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 142 - 1440, 2987) mMaxBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 3040) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0 mPopOver=off mFreeformTaskPinningState=unpinned} s.28768 fontWeightAdjustment=0 ff=0 bf=0 bts=0 desktop/d dm/n dc/d ?dcui ?dcaf enb/d themeSeq=0} mOverrideConfig={1.1 604mcc1mnc [en_US] ldltr sw411dp w411dp h812dp 560dpi nrml long hdr widecg port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 3040) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 142 - 1440, 2987) mMaxBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 3040) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=standard mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0 mPopOver=off mFreeformTaskPinningState=unpinned} s.1 fontWeightAdjustment=0 ff=0 bf=0 bts=0 desktop/d dm/n dc/d ?dcui ?dcaf enb/d themeSeq=0}}
2022-08-13 16:59:46.165 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: [DP] dp(1) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.reportNextDraw:11374 android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleResized:2204 android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$1200:294 
2022-08-13 16:59:46.169 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
2022-08-13 16:59:46.169 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/Unity: windowFocusChanged: false
2022-08-13 16:59:46.170 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/Choreographer: Skipped 242 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2022-08-13 16:59:46.170 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: onWindowVisibilityChanged(0) false android.view.SurfaceView{cf770a VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-1440,2898 aid=1073741824} of ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]
2022-08-13 16:59:46.170 5610-5610/com.minions.text D/SurfaceView@cf770a: updateSurface: surface is not valid
2022-08-13 16:59:46.173 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/DecorView: notifyKeepScreenOnChanged: keepScreenOn=false
2022-08-13 16:59:46.187 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: Relayout returned: old=(0,142,1440,3040) new=(0,142,1440,3040) req=(1440,2898)0 dur=7 res=0x3 s={true 3850173424} ch=true fn=-1
2022-08-13 16:59:46.188 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: windowStopped(false) true android.view.SurfaceView{cf770a VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-1440,2898 aid=1073741824} of ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]
2022-08-13 16:59:46.194 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: pST: sr = Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2898) sw = 1440 sh = 2898
2022-08-13 16:59:46.195 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: onSSPAndSRT: pl = 0 pt = 0 sx = 1.0 sy = 1.0
2022-08-13 16:59:46.195 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: pST: mTmpTransaction.apply, mTmpTransaction = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@bef161
2022-08-13 16:59:46.195 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: updateSurface: mVisible = true mSurface.isValid() = true
2022-08-13 16:59:46.195 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: updateSurface: mSurfaceCreated = false surfaceChanged = true visibleChanged = true
2022-08-13 16:59:46.195 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: surfaceCreated 1 #1 android.view.SurfaceView{cf770a VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-1440,2898 aid=1073741824}
2022-08-13 16:59:46.196 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: surfaceChanged (1440,2898) 1 #1 android.view.SurfaceView{cf770a VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-1440,2898 aid=1073741824}
2022-08-13 16:59:46.196 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: [DP] dp(2) 1 android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface:1375 android.view.SurfaceView.setWindowStopped:383 android.view.SurfaceView.surfaceCreated:2051 
2022-08-13 16:59:46.196 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: [DP] pdf(1) 1 android.view.SurfaceView.notifyDrawFinished:599 android.view.SurfaceView.performDrawFinished:586 android.view.SurfaceView.$r8$lambda$st27mCkd9jfJkTrN_P3qIGKX6NY:0 
2022-08-13 16:59:46.205 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/BufferQueueProducer: [ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]#2(BLAST Consumer)2](id:15ea00000002,api:2,p:5610,c:5610) queueBuffer: queued for the first time.
2022-08-13 16:59:46.206 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: [DP] pdf(0) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw:5181 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:4186 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2893 
2022-08-13 16:59:46.206 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: [DP] rdf()
2022-08-13 16:59:46.206 5610-5610/com.minions.text D/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: reportDrawFinished (fn: -1) 
2022-08-13 16:59:46.223 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
2022-08-13 16:59:46.223 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/Unity: windowFocusChanged: true
2022-08-13 16:59:46.225 5610-5610/com.minions.text D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2022-08-13 16:59:46.225 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2022-08-13 16:59:55.808 5610-5610/com.minions.text D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2022-08-13 16:59:55.809 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2022-08-13 16:59:56.153 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/Unity: onPause
2022-08-13 16:59:59.685 5610-5694/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: Resizing android.view.ViewRootImpl@9f2fb40: frame=[0,142][1440,3040] reportDraw=true forceLayout=false backDropFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2898)
2022-08-13 17:00:00.154 5610-5610/com.minions.text W/Unity: Timeout while trying to pause the Unity Engine.
2022-08-13 17:00:00.162 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: handleAppVisibility mAppVisible=true visible=false
2022-08-13 17:00:00.164 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: stopped(true) old=false
2022-08-13 17:00:00.164 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: windowStopped(true) false android.view.SurfaceView{cf770a VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-1440,2898 aid=1073741824} of ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]
2022-08-13 17:00:00.165 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: pST: sr = Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2898) sw = 1440 sh = 2898
2022-08-13 17:00:00.165 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: onSSPAndSRT: pl = 0 pt = 0 sx = 1.0 sy = 1.0
2022-08-13 17:00:00.165 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: pST: mTmpTransaction.apply, mTmpTransaction = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@bef161
2022-08-13 17:00:00.166 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: surfaceDestroyed callback.size 1 #1 android.view.SurfaceView{cf770a VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-1440,2898 aid=1073741824}
2022-08-13 17:00:04.167 5610-5610/com.minions.text W/Unity: Timeout while trying detaching primary window.
2022-08-13 17:00:04.167 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: updateSurface: mVisible = false mSurface.isValid() = true
2022-08-13 17:00:04.167 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: remove() android.view.SurfaceView{cf770a VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-1440,2898 aid=1073741824} Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.minions.text/com.minions.text.UnityPlayerActivity@cf770a@1)/@0xc220b3b
2022-08-13 17:00:04.179 5610-5610/com.minions.text D/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - Id : 0
2022-08-13 17:00:04.179 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2022-08-13 17:00:04.184 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: handleAppVisibility mAppVisible=false visible=true
2022-08-13 17:00:04.184 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: stopped(false) old=true
2022-08-13 17:00:04.186 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/ViewRootImpl@a49a629[UnityPlayerActivity]: stopped(false) old=false
2022-08-13 17:00:04.186 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/Unity: onResume
2022-08-13 17:00:04.187 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/DecorView: notifyKeepScreenOnChanged: keepScreenOn=false
2022-08-13 17:02:46.491 5610-5625/com.minions.text D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=116
2022-08-13 17:02:49.469 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: remove() android.view.SurfaceView{cf770a VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-1440,2898 aid=1073741824} Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.minions.text/com.minions.text.UnityPlayerActivity@cf770a@2)/@0x8c115ed
2022-08-13 17:02:49.504 5610-5610/com.minions.text D/SurfaceView@cf770a: updateSurface: surface is not valid
2022-08-13 17:00:00.166 5610-5610/com.minions.text I/SurfaceView@cf770a: surfaceDestroyed callback.size 1 #1 android.view.SurfaceView{cf770a VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-1440,2898 aid=1073741824}
2022-08-13 17:00:04.167 5610-5610/com.minions.text W/Unity: Timeout while trying detaching primary window.
```

please if you have any information help on!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.